# Oracle: Regular expression for dot

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

For example, I have a table "example" which has a column "col1" with string like below

```
some example text here x2.0.3-a abc
some other example text 1.5 abc
another example text 0.1.4 mnp
some other example text  abc
another example text mnp
```

I want to select those rows that matches a regular expression. I want the regular expression something like this

`any string.any string.any string space abc/mnp`  or `any string.any string space abc/mnp` that is the regular expression should match two or three dots, before and after of each dot there should be at least one string(char/number/special chars) and then a single space and then at the end either `abc/mnp`. What will be the regular expression and sql query for this?

Comment: Please tell us which of the above 5 rows should match, and why that is the case.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think none because those have no dots? Weird though. Waiting for OP to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Check on the next regex `^[^.]+?(\.[^.]+?){1,2} (abc|mnp)$`.

To try the regular expression online, click [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9a7a994ffd9fc137be79d83e5c231eb4).

To get an explanation go to [here](https://regex101.com/r/K76hLQ/4).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i got your question right , but in case if you are looking to select columns which has any.any or any.any.any in your column then the below regex can help

```
^.*?(\S+\.\S+).*[ ](?:abc|mnp)$
```

[Demo here](https://regex101.com/r/0O3m2D/1/)

Comment: Your regexp doesn't work in [Oracle 11g Release 2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=905eff8e74e25bfa676c8597d0000cb5). Correct it, please.